# Unable to get page numbers to appear in Bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I'm trying to set up pagination using the following: http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/index.html

My code looks like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/bb0y3vg9/1

**What's working:**

The data that I'm returning from the back end is appearing in my table.

**What's Not Working**

I don't get any buttons that allow me to page through the results.  So even though I have more than 10 records in the database, I only ever see 10 results.

```
 Showing 1 to 10 of 10 rows
```

is what appears on my page. 
I've tried to go through all the "data-" options on the table to match it to what exists in the example. I did find that if use the following setting:

```
 data-show-pagination-switch ="true"
```

then the system creates a little button for me above the table.  when you click on the button, it switches between returning all the data in one shot, or returning 10 records only.

But I still can't see the code in the example that creates the buttons under the table to the right with the list of page numbers.

Any suggestions would be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
data-pagination="true"
```